# Is it possible to add <key, value> pair at the end of the dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

When I introduce new  pair it is inserted at the beginning of dictionary. Is it possible to append it at the end?

Comment: possibly look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As of Python 3.7, [dictionaries remember the insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/1258041). By simply adding a new value, you can be sure that it will be "at the end" if you iterate over the dictionary.

---

Dictionaries have no order, and thus have no beginning or end. The display order is arbitrary.
If you need order, you can use a `list` of `tuple`s instead of a `dict`:

```
In [1]: mylist = []

In [2]: mylist.append(('key', 'value'))

In [3]: mylist.insert(0, ('foo', 'bar'))
```

You'll be able to easily convert it into a `dict` later:

```
In [4]: dict(mylist)
Out[4]: {'foo': 'bar', 'key': 'value'}
```

Alternatively, use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) as suggested by IamAlexAlright.

Answer (score 7):

A `dict` in Python is not "ordered" - in Python 2.7+ there's `collections.OrderedDict`, but apart from that - no... The key point of a dictionary in Python is efficient key->lookup value... The order you're seeing them in is completely arbitrary depending on the hash algorithm...

Comment: It depends on the hash algorithm and also the order the items are inserted (when collisions happen).

Comment: @mgilson Yup - completely different from a C++ `map` - which ensures ordering of keys - etc.. etc...

Comment: I wouldn't know about C++ ... My first programming class was C++ and I *hated* it.  I thought programming was the stupidest thing ever.  Ironically, eventually I grew to like programming when I started programming in C and then Fortran after that (seems like I went backwards quite a bit).  And python, Fortan and C are pretty much the only languages that I code in now -- with a little shell scripting here and there when necessary.

Comment: @mgilson I'm not sure there's a "good" language to learn with... all have their own strengths/weaknesses and it's only after time you "get it" (or at least you *think* you get it)... I'm quite lucky 'cos I think I'm competent with Python, but also have others under my belt, so who knows... It feels painful to program C again though ;)

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem was that they were trying to teach me to program instead of trying to teach me to do something interesting using programming.  Once I had a solid reason to write programs to solve interesting problems, it became a lot more fun.  And you can imagine that when I get to program in C, it's like driving a Cadillac compared to writing Fortran code (*I can group a bunch of arguments together and call it a "struct"?  Cool!*).  Of course, that makes Python a Ferrari ( In terms of coding experience at least -- Not exactly in terms of performance of the resulting program :-D )

Answer (score 5):

No. Check the OrderedDict from collections module.

Answer (score 0):

dictionary data is inorder collection 
if u add data to dict use this :
**Adding a new key value pair**

```
Dic.update( {'key' : 'value' } )
```

**If key is string you can directly add without curly braces**

```
Dic.update( key= 'value' )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend for updated values to move to the end of the `dict` then you can pop the key first then update the `dict`.

For example:

```
In [1]: number_dict = {str(index): index for index in range(10)}
In [2]: number_dict.update({"3": 13})
In [3]: number_dict
Out[3]: 
{'0': 0,
 '1': 1,
 '2': 2,
 '3': 13,
 '4': 4,
 '5': 5,
 '6': 6,
 '7': 7,
 '8': 8,
 '9': 9}

In [4]: number_dict = {str(index): index for index in range(10)}
In [5]: number_dict.pop("3", None)
In [6]: number_dict.update({"3": 13})
In [7]: number_dict
Out[7]: 
{'0': 0,
 '1': 1,
 '2': 2,
 '4': 4,
 '5': 5,
 '6': 6,
 '7': 7,
 '8': 8,
 '9': 9,
 '3': 13}
```