# How to ensure update() adds to end of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've read that [OrderedDict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110627/print-original-input-order-of-dictionary-in-python) can be used to keep information in a dictionary in order, but it seems to require that you input the information while instantiating the dictionary itself.

However, I need to be able to use update() multiple times in a for loop and ensure the each entry gets added to the *end* of the dictionary. Is there a way to do that?

Here's a visual of what I'm talking about

```
for e in entryList:
    myDict.update({e[2]: e[3]})
```

This enters all the new info, but doesn't keep it in order.

Comment: `append()` for OrderedDict? Are you sure there is one?

Comment: So I suggest just go with the recommendations from this post again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239279/is-it-possible-to-add-key-value-pair-at-the-end-of-the-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) you'll have to delete the entry before adding it.

You can wrap this in a subclass for convenience..:

```
class MyOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def update(self, other):
        for k, v in other.items():
            if k in self:
                 del self[k]
            self[k] = v
```

it seems strange to use update the way you do though:

```
myDict.update({e[2]: e[3]})
```

since it would be more clear to write:

```
myDict[e[2]] = e[3]
```

to make that work you'll also need to override `__setitem__`

```
class MyOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if key in self:
             del self[key]
        super(self, MyOrderedDict).__setitem__(key, val)

    def update(self, other):
        for k, v in other.items():
            self[k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bob, please refer to the docs here. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict

It says:

> The OrderedDict constructor and update() method both accept keyword
>   arguments, but their order is lost because Python’s function call
>   semantics pass in keyword arguments using a regular unordered
>   dictionary.

However, there's a workaround added in 3.2: (from the same page)

> move_to_end(key, last=True) Move an existing key to either end of an
>   ordered dictionary. The item is moved to the right end if last is true
>   (the default) or to the beginning if last is false. Raises KeyError if
>   the key does not exist.

I hope that answers the question.